# Exception while sending an email in Java with javax.mail

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to do an Android app that sends an image automatically without any intervention from the user.

I'm using `javax.mail` jar (and the `activation.jar` and `additional.jar`) in order to do so.
I'm doing the following

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",true);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(USER,PASS);
    }
});

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("*******@gmail.com"));
message.setSubject("Email Subject");

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                     new InternetAddress("******@gmail.com"));

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent("<img src=\"image.gif\"/>","text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(ruta));
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("picture.gif");
messageBodyPart.setDisposition("inline");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error

> W/System.err(24907): javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   W/System.err(24907):   nested exception is:
>   W/System.err(24907):  javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;
>   W/System.err(24907):  boundary="----=_Part_0_1095625208.1397499270313"
>   W/System.err(24907):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1182)
>   W/System.err(24907):  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
>   W/System.err(24907):  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

Any idea on how can I solve this?

I'm using a `Debian 64-bits` computer and `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - Kepler`. if it's needed for the solution...

Comment: What is the java mail api version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DCH` is Data Content Handler. `MimeType` handlers seem to be not configured correctly.

If you can download and use latest `1.5.*` version of java mail api, this error should be getting resolved.

Otherwise, within the code you can execute some statements to set the `MimeType` handlers.

Add following code snippet to your mail module and is available for the mail `Session`.

```
MailcapCommandMap mailcapCommandMap = new MailcapCommandMap(); 
mailcapCommandMap.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; x-java-fallback-entry=true"); 
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcapCommandMap);
```

You can extend this for additional `MimeTypes`

```
mailcapCommandMap.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mailcapCommandMap.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mailcapCommandMap.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mailcapCommandMap.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
```

***Refer To***:

- [*javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.addMailcap(java.lang.String)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/activation/MailcapCommandMap.html#addMailcap%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Add entries to the registry. Programmatically added entries are
    searched before other entries.

Apart from this method, read entire documentation on this class.

Comment: Thanks, this piece of code made it finally work. I was using the java mail version 1.5.1 but withouth that code it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem for my release mode android app, it works as expected for the debug mode.

Adding the following lines in the proguard file will fix the problem:

```
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.**
-dontwarn com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base
```